# Using a Static Class function to create a Singleton object/instance

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a static member function that returns a pointer to one instance of the class. Is this possible in C++?

```
    class DynamicMemoryLog
{
    // Singleton Class:

    public:

        static DynamicMemoryLog* CreateLog();
        void   AddIObject( IUnknown* obj );
        void   ReleaseDynamicMemory();

    private:
        // static DynamicMemoryLog* instance;
        static bool isAlive;  // used to determine is an instance of DynamicMemoryLog already exists

        DynamicMemoryLog();
        ~DynamicMemoryLog();

        std::vector <IUnknown*> iObjectList;
};
```

This function below should create a new instance of the class & return a pointer to that object, but the compiler will not allow me to define a static function of the class if it returns a pointer(I think thats why it wont compile?):

```
static DynamicMemoryLog* DynamicMemoryLog :: CreateLog()
{
    // Post:

    if ( !isAlive )   // ( instance == NULL; )
    {
       DynamicMemoryLog* instance  = new DynamicMemoryLog();
       return instance;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: DynamicMemoryLog.cpp(17): error C2724: 'DynamicMemoryLog::CreateLog' : 'static' should not be used on member functions defined at file scop

Comment: just a reminder, if you have more than one singleton class linked or depend each other, logging classes should be removed or released as last during program exit. Therefore, please keep in mind "object life time" management. It is usually skipped by most developers.

Answer (score 2):

The particular error you're getting is that when implementing a static member function, you don't repeat the static keyword.  Fixing this should resolve the error.

Independently, there's something a bit odd with your code.  You claim that this object is a singleton, but each call to CreateLog will create a new instance of the class.  Do you really want this behavior, or do you want there to be many copies?  I'd suggest looking into this before proceeding.

Comment: Ah, so I dont put static at the begininng when implementing the static function. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest solution, but not thread-safe. For analysis in detail, have a look at [this article](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf).

```
class DynamicMemoryLog 
{
public:
   static DynamicMemoryLog* GetInstance();
private:
   DynamicMemoryLog();
   static DynamicMemoryLog* m_pInstance;
}

DynamicMemoryLog* DynamicMemoryLog::GetInstance()
{
   if(!m_pInstance)    
   {
      m_pInstance = new DynamicMemoryLog();       
   }     

   return m_pInstance;
}
```

Comment: If GetInstance() is not static, I wont be able to do this will I... DynamicMemoryLog *dm = DynamicMemoryLog :: GetInstance(); ?

Comment: @Sascha Static member methods can access only static class' attributes

Comment: @Sascha You would usually access other members through DynamicMemoryLog::GetInstance(), e.g.  `DynamicMemoryLog::GetInstance()->AddIObject(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
class Singleton
{
    public:

        static Singleton* get()
        {
            static Singleton instance;
            return &instance;
        }
};
```

This way you won't have any nasty memory management issues.

Comment: Will that variable, instance, will be persistant throughout & fall out of scope?

Comment: @Sascha: what do you mean with persistent *and* fall out of scope? The variable `instance` will be constructed when `get()` is called for the first time and destructed on program exit (or on dynamic library unload when the class lives in a library).